# Can "buy" be understandable when used intransitively?

Tags: verbs

> The smart phone buys well all over the world among teenagers

I want to convey similarly with the sentence that the smart phone is bought well all over the world among teenagers.

For me to read, it could be understandable because no one would think the smart phone buys something like a human, so the only possible translation is the above.

Though such an usage isn't registered on any dictionaries, and so unnatural, I think it could be acceptable If someone started to use it.

Comment: You could say "The smartphone *is a great buy* among teenagers around the world."

Answer (score 3):

You can say something *sells well* to mean it is easy to sell.  This is usually in a context of business or moneymaking - the normal implication is that it's easy to make money by selling this item.

None of that applies to *buy well* - and using the adverb *well* with *buy* is rare.

Converting your sentence to use the verb *sell* will resolve.  You also want to be explicit about teenagers being something that the phone is sold to, to avoid sounding like you are talking about teenagers doing the selling:

> The smart phone sells well to teenagers all over the world

If you really want to say something to the effect of "teenagers are very willing to buy phones all over the world", the adverb *well* won't help you.

Comment: If one were to say "She **buys well**", it would be understood to mean she is a smart shopper who conscientiously checks prices or buys at a good price.